# How to render field data into a template file using django?

Tags: python, xml, django

I am trying to render data into a template file using the following Code. The error I encounter is something like :

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 13 at column 16: AttValue: " or ' expected

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
Name,Author,Status
```

**Code**

```
def editbook(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        name = request.GET.get('name',False)
        Details = bookInfo.objects.all().filter(Name=name)
        id = Details.values_list('id',flat=True)
        Name = Details.values_list('Name',flat=True)
        Author = Details.values_list('Author',flat=True)
        Status = Details.values_list('Status',flat=True)
        return render(request, 'app/add.html', {'Name' : Name, 'Author' : Author, 'Status' : Status}, content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

**Template Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="add/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p style="font-family:Courier New;color:teal">Name <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the book" name="name"></input></p>

        <p style="font-family:Courier New;color:teal">Author <input type="text" placeholder="Author of the book" name="author"></input></p>
        <p style="font-family:Courier New; color:teal"> Status
        <select name="status">
                <option value=1>Read</option>
                <option value=1>Unread</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="booksubmit" value="Add/Edit Book"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched through Google and I found that this somewhat like XML parsing error (Please correct me if I am wrong). Now I am stuck at this position. Please help.

**EDIT** Here the form for adding the book has a different method for saving the field data into database.

Comment: Can you show `app/add.html` template?

Comment: @Ander2 I have added the template code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed for whatever type is is, html and html5.

And to be picky, your python code should be refactored as well.

Normally we define variables with lowercase letter instead of a capital so

the variables `Details, Name, Author, Status` should be `details, name, author, status`.
Further more, is your class name `bookInfo` spelled like that?
Classes in python should start with a capital letter so `bookInfo` should be `BookInfo`.

The proper HTML5 is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="add/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p style="font-family:Courier New;color:teal;">Name <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the book" name="name" /></p>

        <p style="font-family:Courier New;color:teal;">Author <input type="text" placeholder="Author of the book" name="author" /></p>
        <p style="font-family:Courier New; color:teal;"> Status
            <select name="status">
                <option value=1>Read</option>
                <option value=1>Unread</option>
            </select>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" id="booksubmit" value="Add/Edit Book" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're not using HTML5 and that depends on the Doctype you've defined.
You can't use placeholders in your input fields.

The inputs need to get closed with a `/>` and not a `</input>`.

The inline styles you've provided in your html is incomplete:

```
style="font-family:Courier New; color:teal"
```

should be

```
style="font-family:Courier New; color:teal;"
```

The return you're using doesn't need a `content_type` you can drop that.
You're not using your template variables anywhere so that's not it but if you would like to start using them the syntax for the template language is {{ variable_name }} and in your case that would be (until you refactor)
`{{ Name }}, {{ Status }}` for example.

Also you're seeing this error because of the `content_type` since you're actively telling the browser to parse the document as `xhtml+xml` and that's XHTML with rules, which you're effectively breaking.

For adding the value from your Django app to your input fields do this, (without a Django Form)

```
<input type="text" value="{{ Name }}" />
```

But I would recommend using a Django Form instead.

Comment: I have changed the code but i still face the same issue. Is it because I am trying to fill the content into the `text-fields` rather than directly rendering to the template?

Comment: Are you using any javascript?

Comment: All right, the only place where I can imagine that you're having issues then is the `<option value=1>` Try enclosing the 1 in `""`. Also what doctype is your HTML?

Comment: Well, I want value of `Status` to be `integers`. Still I tried inserting the quotation marks with no success. I haven't used `doctype` in my document.

Comment: All right, the HTML isn't malformed anywhere. Is this all of your code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25756/discussion-between-mozart-and-limelights)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting this error because you're template is not 'well formed'. My guess is that there's an error in the xml that's being output.

You've declared the content type of your http response to be `application/xhtml+xml`. xhtml requires you to put quotes around all your attributes. You're probably missing/adding a quotation mark somewhere. I can't see from your template where that is.

Either check what your template variables (`{{ Name }}`, `{{ Author }}` and `{{ Status }}`) are outputting to see if they're adding in a stray quotation mark, or try changing the content type (maybe just drop the content_type parameter you're passing to the `render` function).

Comment: Is my `render` statement(the syntax) correct? Well I tried removing the `content_type`, its of no use. But then I tried changing `{'Name' : Name, 'Author' : Author, 'Status' : Status}` with `({{'Name' : Name}},{{ 'Author' : Author}},{{ 'Status' : Status}})`, it says: `unhashable dict`. What to do?

Comment: You have a malformed dict, you cant go `{{}}` a dict is 1 pair of `{}`.

Comment: @limelights So does that mean , my previous syntax was correct?